# NASM JLE: Jump if Less or Equal always evaluating to true

Tags: nasm, conditional-statements

I have code here that reads in input to determine the dimensions of a matrix/2d array and then reads in numbers one by one. Then it is SUPPOSED to spit out the smallest number.

However my comparison operator doesn't seem to be working? I've tried putting both as registers, with different variables and so on but for some reason eax with whatever happened to be the first entry in the array is ALWAYS smaller than the next number, even if this is clearly not the case.

So it always skips reassignment.

Code: Just skip straight to cmp eax,[num]
My guess is something is causing num, perhaps how its declared? Is always 'larger' than eax, is there extra fluff I am not aware of?

```
segment .bss
  num: resw 1 ;For storing a number, to be read of printed....
  nod: resb 1 ;For storing the number of digits....
  temp: resb 2
  matrix1: resw 200
  m: resw 1
  n: resw 1
  i: resw 1
  j: resw 1
  small: resb 4         ; temp variable
  buff resb 4

segment .data
  msg1: db "Enter the number of rows in the matrix : "
  msg_size1: equ $-msg1
  msg2:  db "Enter the elements one by one(row by row) : "
  msg_size2: equ $-msg2
  msg3: db "Enter the number of columns in the matrix : "
  msg_size3: equ $-msg3
  msg4: db "The Smallest Number is... : "
  msg_size4: equ $-msg4

  tab: db  9 ;ASCII for vertical tab
  new_line: db 10 ;ASCII for new line

segment .text

global _start

_start:

    ;; code for reading number of rows and columns, this works fine.
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, msg1
  mov edx, msg_size1
  int 80h
    ;; read in rows
  mov ecx, 0
  call read_num  
  mov cx, word[num]
  mov word[m], cx
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, msg3
  mov edx, msg_size3
  int 80h
    ;; read in columns
  mov ecx, 0
  call read_num  
  mov cx, word[num]
  mov word[n], cx
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, msg2
  mov edx, msg_size2
  int 80h
    ;; Reading in each element and storing it into the array
  mov esi, 0
  mov ebx, matrix1  
    ;; init loop
  mov word[i], 0
  mov word[j], 0

    ;; Outer loop
  i_loop:
    mov word[j], 0
    ;; Inner Loop
    j_loop:

    ;; A function
 call read_num
    ;; Result of that function is now stored int he matrix
 mov dx , word[num]
 mov  word[ebx + 2 * esi], dx 

 inc esi    ;Incrementing array index by one....
 inc word[j]
 mov cx, word[j]
 cmp cx, word[n]
 jb j_loop
    ;; End Inner Loop
    inc word[i]
    mov cx, word[i]
    cmp cx, word[m]
    jb i_loop
    ;; End Outer Loop

    ;;  Now begins the code to find the smallest number
    mov eax, [matrix1]
    ;; Moves first element of Matrix1 into eax

    ;;; saves eax into small
    mov [small], eax
  ;Loop through the matrix, check each number if its smaller than the first number in the array. AT the end print said number.

    ;Reading each element of the matrix.(Storing the elements in row major order).......
  mov esi, 0
  mov edi, matrix1

    ;; Reinit loop cters
  mov word[i], 0
  mov word[j], 0

    ;; Loop
  i_loop2:
    mov word[j], 0
    j_loop2:

   ;eax will contain the array index and each element is 2 bytes(1 word) long
   mov  dx, word[edi+2*esi]   ;
   mov word[num] , dx

    cmp eax,[num] ; compares eax and ebx
    jle   skip   ;if eax is SMALLER than ebx, we can safely skip reassignment
             ;as our current value is already smallest.
    mov eax, [num] ; stores new smallest number if the new number was smaller.
    mov [small], eax
    ;; reassignment code is always skipped.
    skip:

 inc esi
 inc word[j]
 mov cx, word[j]
 cmp cx, word[n]
 jb j_loop2

    inc word[i]
    mov cx, word[i]
    cmp cx, word[m]
    jb i_loop2

    ; code to output the smallest number
    ;;  Some ui text.
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1            
  mov ecx, msg4
  mov edx, msg_size4
  int 80h
  mov ecx, 0

    ;; Now the actual smallest number   
    mov eax, 4  ; system_write
    mov ebx, 1  ; stdout
    mov ecx, [small]    ; move smallest element to accumulator
    add ecx, 48         ; convert to ascii representation
    mov [buff], ecx     ; move to memory
    mov ecx, buff
    mov edx, 4          ; size, 4 bytes
    int 80h

exit:
  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 80h

;Function to read a number from console and to store that in num 
read_num:

  pusha
  mov word[num], 0

  loop_read:
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, temp
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h

    cmp byte[temp], 10
      je end_read

    mov ax, word[num]
    mov bx, 10
    mul bx
    mov bl, byte[temp]
    sub bl, 30h
    mov bh, 0
    add ax, bx
    mov word[num], ax   

    jmp loop_read 
  end_read:
  popa

ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes, several hours of fidgeting and seconds after this post I figured out exactly why. Turns out yes, the way I declared "num" yes indeed added in extra information. I changed it to resb 4 and it works.

Crabbaskets.